# Why does this seemingly equivalent SecurityManager code cause spurious exceptions?

Tags: java, security, securitymanager, accesscontrolexception

This question is a follow-up to [my previous question about unusual exceptions generated by a custom security manager.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527776/why-does-my-custom-securitymanager-cause-exceptions-the-16th-time-i-create-an-ob) At a high level, I am interested in building an application that runs trusted code alongside untrusted code. My initial idea was to build a custom `SecurityManager` that would disallow most operations from running. This led to unusual behavior where trusted reflective code instantiating untrusted objects failed after 16 invocations.

I have rewritten the code so that instead of using a custom `SecurityManager` to handle this, I instead create a new protection domain in which the untrusted code runs and then strip permissions from that untrusted code. This new code is shown here:

```
import java.io.FilePermission;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.security.*;

public class Main {
    /* Track how many instances have been created so that we can see when the exception
     * is thrown.
     */
    private static int numInstances = 0;
    public Main() {
        System.out.println("Number created: " + ++numInstances);
    }

    /* Utility function that returns a Constructor object for main. */
    private static Constructor<Main> getCtor() {
        try {
            return Main.class.getConstructor();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
            return null; // Unreachable, needed to appease compiler.
        }
    }

    /* Utility function that creates an AccessControlContext that only has file
     * read permissions.
     */
    private static AccessControlContext getContext() {
        CodeSource c = new CodeSource(null, (java.security.cert.Certificate[])null);
        Permissions permissions = new Permissions();

        /* Grant specific permission to read files. This is necessary, since otherwise the
         * class loader can't read classes from disk.
         */
        permissions.add(new FilePermission("*", "read"));

        /* Construct an AccessControlContext from these permissions. */
        return new AccessControlContext(new ProtectionDomain[] {new ProtectionDomain(c, permissions)});
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Get a very restrictive AccessControlContext that does not allow for anything to run. */
        AccessControlContext noPermissions = getContext();

        /* Install a standard security manager to enable security. */
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());

        /* Sit in an infinite loop using reflection to create Main objects.  This code is
         * run in a context where its only permissions are file reading.
         */
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void run() {
                /* Continuously create new Main objects. */
                Constructor<Main> ctor = getCtor();
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        ctor.newInstance();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }, noPermissions);

    }
}
```

This code now works perfectly fine - it constructs all sorts of `Main` objects without any trouble whatsoever.

What I'm confused about is the following. In order for the `AccessController` to have any teeth, we need to have the security manager turned on. I do this by calling

```
/* Install a standard security manager to enable security. */
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
```

Now, suppose I change this from the *default* `SecurityManager` to this custom `SecurityManager`:

```
/* Install a standard security manager to enable security. */
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
    @Override
    public void checkPermission(Permission p) {
         /* Log the permission. */
         System.out.println("Checking " + p);
         super.checkPermission(p);
    }
});
```

This `SecurityManager` is identical to before, except that it logs what happens when a permission is checked and then forwards the request to the default `SecurityManager`.

If I make this change and run the program, I now get the same behavior as before:

```
Checking ("java.io.FilePermission" "/home/keith/Documents/secret-eclipse-workspace/Security Manager Test/bin/Main$2.class" "read")
Checking ("java.io.FilePermission" "/home/keith/Documents/secret-eclipse-workspace/Security Manager Test/bin/Main$2.class" "read")
Checking ("java.io.FilePermission" "/home/keith/Documents/secret-eclipse-workspace/Security Manager Test/bin/Main$2.class" "read")
Number created: 1
Number created: 2
Number created: 3
Number created: 4
Number created: 5
Number created: 6
Number created: 7
Number created: 8
Number created: 9
Number created: 10
Number created: 11
Number created: 12
Number created: 13
Number created: 14
Number created: 15
Checking ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "createClassLoader")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "createClassLoader")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at Main$1.checkPermission(Main.java:51)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkCreateClassLoader(SecurityManager.java:611)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCreateClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:274)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.<init>(ClassLoader.java:316)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader.<init>(ClassDefiner.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner$1.run(ClassDefiner.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner$1.run(ClassDefiner.java:58)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at Main$2.run(Main.java:65)
    at Main$2.run(Main.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at Main.main(Main.java:58)
```

Why am I getting different behavior before and after using this custom `SecurityManager`? I don't understand why the program would produce different results in these cases, since in both cases the default `SecurityManager` is the one actually making all of the security checks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your `SecurityManager` does not appear to be trusted. So when it appear during stack inspection, the security check will fail.

Why doesn't the code `main` and `run` cause the same problem? We can see from the stack trace those stack elements that are involved in the security check.

```
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at Main$1.checkPermission(Main.java:51)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkCreateClassLoader(SecurityManager.java:611)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCreateClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:274)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.<init>(ClassLoader.java:316)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader.<init>(ClassDefiner.java:72)
at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner$1.run(ClassDefiner.java:60)
at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner$1.run(ClassDefiner.java:58)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:57)
```

The only non-system frame there is `Main$1.checkPermission(Main.java:51)`. Remove it and the problem disappears.

Comment: Thanks! How would I make that code trusted? Or should I be looking for a totally different approach?

Comment: @templatetypedef Generally you would grant the codebase `java.security.AllPermission` in a policy file.